# How can I make a div with a box-shadow overlay its h1 child element?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a `box-shadow` and an `h1` inside, but the shadow doesn't cover the `h1`

Here is my code:

```css
h1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 44%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-44%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-44%, -50%);
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 120px;
    text-align: center;
}

#div{
    width:100%;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
    height:400px;
    
}
```

```html
<div id="div"><h1>hi</h1></div>
```

Comment: I am not trying to be a smartass or anything but I would not expect my own shadow to come over my face. The shadow is supposed to go behind the element.

Comment: What about `h1{ color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0); }` ;)

Comment: Are you looking for text-shadow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears from your question that you want the `div` shadow to cover the `h1`.

To accomplish this simply apply a negative `z-index` to the `h1`.

```
h1 { z-index: -1; }
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/rzhfqb5y/

The shadow now covers the `h1`.

Comment: @Michael_B +1 for being able to decipher that question. It was poorly-worded.